# Does $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2-1$ converge to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ in distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $(X_n)_n\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be independent variables
> and $\mathbb{E}(X_1^4)=3$. Does $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum
>  \limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_i^2-1)$ converge to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ in
> distribution?

I think: yes. Here's my attempt:

This does hint at the strong law of large numbers, we have to square $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum
 \limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_i^2-1)$.$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_i^2-1)\right)^2=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_i^2-1)\right)^2 $$ Is this, as $n\to \infty$, equal to $E(X_i^2-1)^2$? Or is "$\mathbb{E}(X_1^4)=3$" a trick to throw one off?

Comment: Are the $X_n$ supposed to be $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$? There is no $\mu$ or $\sigma^2$ in the rest of the problem.

Comment: @angryavian Yes, you're right! I will correct that.

Comment: @Analysis I think $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2-1\right)^2=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2-1\right)^2$ should be $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2-1\right)^2=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2-\sqrt{n}\right)^2$

Comment: Why is that? I don't understand. @KB

Comment: Its probably a calculation mistake. Please check the calculation once.

Comment: Also, the minimum value of $ K_n := \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2-1$  is $-1$. That is, irrespective of $n$, $P(K_n < -1) = 0$ which is nowhere near the normal distribution.

Comment: @KB I did not calculate anything at all. It's a question from an old test, a multiple choice question. It could be wrong.

Comment: I assume the parentheses are supposed to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n( X_i^2-1)$? Otherwise, as KB says, it is strictly $>=-1$ so that tells you right away that it isn't normal. (And in fact it goes to infinity in this case.)

Comment: $$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2-1\right)^2=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2-1\right)^2 $$ This part is clearly wrong. And I agree with @spaceisdarkgreen and KB

Comment: My sincere apologies. I edited the question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite confident, notwithstanding confusion in the comments, that the expression is intended to be read as $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i^2-1).$$ The $X_i^2-1$ are i.i.d. random variables with mean $0$ and variance $2$, so immediately the central limit theorem implies that the series converges in distribution to $N(0,2).$

Comment: I think so too but OP hasn't specified it yet. In case it is as written, then there is no convergence to a proper random variable.

Comment: Yes, you interpreted it correctly. I could have been more precise, I apologise!